# Animated cursor in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, cursor

Is it possible to use animated cursors in tkinter window like using custom cursor with widgets. To use custom ani cursors on root window of tkinter file

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: *Offtopic: it reminds me time when the only fun on Windows was change cursor to banana*.

Comment: This page says that for Windows it *should be possilble* to use custom .CUR or .ANI files: https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/cursors

Comment: @Ronald is der a way to set cursor for the whole root window rather than jus widgets

Comment: @OlvinRoght dem days xd

Comment: @Cool Cloud: yes, the root window (or whatever you called it) has the method `root.config(cursor='some_cursor' `. See for example [Displaying a Busy Cursor](https://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-busy.htm) on effbot.

Comment: thanks :) if u add as an ans ill mark as d correct ans

Comment: @Ronald what abt cursor packages, like loading cursor and selection cursor and all those? how to set those

Comment: It is barely an answer, just a reference to a a page where you can *find* the answer ;-). Here you can find all built-in cursors: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/cursors.htm. Quite a lot...

Answer (score 2):

You can do it. Almost all widgets have `cursor` parameter so you can change the cursor of widgets separately.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
root.configure(cursor="heart")  # Default cursor on main window.

B1 = tk.Button(root, text="circle_cursor", cursor="circle")  # Cursor on Button widget
B1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Possible cursors:**

[image: Cursors]